# I tried making a clear command but some of the code didn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am using VSC and the latest discord.js

The code I used in my separate commands.js folder was:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "clear.message",
    execute(message, args) {
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Enter a number");
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send("Enter a Real number");

        if(args[0] > 15) return message.channel.send("That number is too high! Try again!");
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.channel.sned("Enter a number larger than 1");
    }
}
```

In my index.js file my code was:

```
client.on('message', message => {
 
    const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
    case 'clear':
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
        break;
    }
});
```

However when I tried the command with my bot instead of returning the correct messages, it would just send the message "Enter a Real number" even if I did  `!clear 4`.
Not too sure what is wrong, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: My guess is all params are strings, which means args[0] is `"4"`, not `4`. Call `Number()` on it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `args[0]` when you are looking for a command in `index.js` and also when looking for an argument in `commands.js`. So instead of `4`, your code is trying to parse `clear` as a number.

You can change the index of the `args` to 1 in `commands.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "clear.message",
    execute(message, args) {
        if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Enter a number");
        if(isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send("Enter a Real number");

        if(args[1] > 15) return message.channel.send("That number is too high! Try again!");
        if(args[1] < 1) return message.channel.sned("Enter a number larger than 1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are 0-indexed. Your `args` array looks like this if you input the command `!clear 4`:

```js
["clear", "4"]
```

To access `"4"` you need to use the correct index (`1`).

```js
if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Enter a number");
if(isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send("Enter a Real number");
if(parseInt(args[1] > 15)) return message.channel.send("That number is too high! Try again!");
if(parseInt(args[1] < 1)) return message.channel.send("Enter a number larger than 1"); //there was a typo here!
```